# SPI Reset on Raspberry Pi after GPIO usage

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, spi

I found out when I used GPIO Pins which are also SPI Pins (GPIO8,9,10,11) and clean them up. I can not reuse this Pins for an SPI connection.

I have to restart the Raspberry Pi first to use SPI again.

Do you have an idea how I can reset this Pins for SPI usage without restart?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

use the command `lsmod` to get the name of your `spi` module and simply remove it as follows (assuming `spi_bcm2708` is module name),

```
rmmod spi_bcm2708
```

then reload it as follows,

```
modprobe spi_bcm2708
```

try with `sudo` if doesn't work.